# Iptables log analysis tool, not reporting tool?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, redhat, open-source

I'm running a RHEL 6 Linux server and receive about 3000-5000 hits on my iptables logs daily and I want to see all hits on the iptables, source address, source network name, ports, hit counts etc.

Is there any advanced iptables *analysis* tool that can evaluate attacks in server through any web interface, which is what I'm really interested in?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a monitoring tool, you can use Snort like khaled suggested, another Open source tool is [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/).

It has many rules to provide monitoring for webservers,mailservers,ssh authentication... It sends you an email when things look fishy and can also, when configured, block those IP's. They have  server-client model. I wrote an introduction and guide on how to use it [here](http://cloud101.eu/blog/2012/03/01/ossec-keeping-your-system-safe-from-nasty-scanners-and-attackers/).

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at [Intrusion Detection Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_Detection_System)? [Snort](http://www.snort.org/) is a well-known open-source IDS. This software can sit on your gateway and monitor your traffic to raise alarms/alerts based on different criteria.

Answer (score 1):

A nice and simple tool would be [fwanalog](http://tud.at/programm/fwanalog/). It is based on the old [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/) package that provides anaylsis for Apache logs. FWanalog is fairly quick to setup and provides some nice high level breakdown of the firewall blocks.

For more in depth reporting I would look at something more like Splunk or OSSEC, both of which are excellent tools. FWanalog, however, can be setup and trialed significantly faster, however.